# Multiple calls to same function doing calculation, need a better way to handle it

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, .net-core

So, this is the scenario.

There is a static class which does some calculations based on the data provided.

```
public static class Calculations
{
  public static object Calculate(IList<Class> listOfClass)
  {
     /// going to database and do calculations....
     return calculatedValue;
  }
}
```

Now on page load we are making like 20 AJAX requests simultaneously (only using JQUERY) which is calling different actions in a controller. So for example.

```
public class ClientController
   {
      [HttpPost]
      public IActionResult GetAGraph(Object model)
      {
         var listOfClass = // get data based on the model
         var calculatedValue = Calculations.Calculate(listOfClass);
         var returnObject = //do something with calculatedValue
         return Json(returnObject);
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public IActionResult GetSecondGraph(Object model)
      {
         var listOfClass = // get data based on the model
         var calculatedValue = Calculations.Calculate(listOfClass);
         var returnObject = //do something with calculatedValue
         return Json(returnObject);
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public IActionResult GetThirdGraph(Object model)
      {
         var listOfClass = // get data based on the model
         var calculatedValue = Calculations.Calculate(listOfClass);
         var returnObject = //do something with calculatedValue
         return Json(returnObject);
      }   
   }
```

Its not doing the same thing and the actual code I am not allowed to post because of client terms.

What I want to acheive is not doing the same calculations on every controller action, instead if we can store somewhere globally the calculated value and use that for subsequent calls than it would increase the performance and save a lot of time OR any other solution to not make the same calculation again and again.

NOTE: Cannot use memory cache as new data is uploaded every night and it will affect the calculations.

Thank you all for your help!!

Comment: `we are making like 20 AJAX requests simultaneously` Do not do this. You are basically DDOSing yourself. Change your logic to make a single request. This will then also solve your second problem of storing the calculated values between calls.

Comment: Yup, thought about that but the way the application works is we need to make multiple ajax requests. bascially, it will load the data as and when it receives and every call returns some or the other data. so, the next thing for me to do is only make calls on scroll but that will still have this problem. Imagine a page with like 20 graphs and some tables and some stats, which needs to be reloaded every time the page loads or some filter is changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to optimize the performance, though recommendations would be a bit limited given scarcity of specifics in your question:

1. Data uploaded every night should not be a showstopper for using memory cache.  Your requests are coming nearly simultaneously, so your cache could be short-lived (say a minute).  When new data is uploaded, you're only behind by about a minute which in many cases could be acceptable.  You can also mark your cache with version of data (i.e. which day) it was constructed with, and thus the moment new data is loaded, ignore and/or purge the cache.  So memory caching is still an option.
2. Precalculating this common interim result (as part of data load) and storing it in the DB, so that on every controller action you start from this common base and just do what is specific for that exact action.
3. Have your client do a pre-request that would serve as basis for the other requests.  On the pre-request, you calculate the common base, issue an id, then have other actions receive this id, load the calculated base off the id, and do their action-specific calculations for final result.  The con here, obviously, is enforcing client into a particular usage of the API, but may be acceptable in your case?
4. If usage pattern is fairly stable - meaning that the set of APIs are frequently called together, simply have a fat API entry point that calculates the base and all specifics of every action in the needed set, and then returns as one massive result, but thus does the common computation only once.

More specifics would help for a more practical answer.

Comment: I would love to share more specifics about this :). Your 3 point is what will work for me and I am going to give it a go with that. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Great.  By the way, #2 and #3 are not that different.  Both have you store result (though #3 could be in shared memory cache).  #3 does allow to limit calculations only when requested, avoiding computations for those that wouldn't be requested.

Answer (score 0):

from what i understood you simply need to store the calculatedValue somwhere !

if you need it only in the same run you can stor it in a static global variable,
you can also store it in a session if the value is different between users,
and if the value is the same for all users you can use a file that will be overwritten every time you need to refresh the calculatedValue;

so if the calculatedValue must change once a day you'll have to refresh it once a day